# Force instantiation of derived type instead of base type

Tags: c++, polymorphism, code-injection, c++03

Assume we have the following, **given** code:

```cpp
class T; // with T::~T is virtual
class S;
class E {
  void foo() {
    /* ... */
    S s;
    T* t = new T(s);
    /* ... */
    delete t;
    /* ... */
  }
};
```

We cannot change `E`.

Assume now that we have:

```cpp
class S;
class A {
  class T : public ::T {
    T(S);
  }
};
```

Is there *any way* (in C++03!) we can force `E` to instantiate `A::T` instead of `::T` in `E::foo`, without changing the implementation of `E::foo` or `E` in general?

Note: If really necessary, it would be acceptable to make `E` inherit from something we specify (e.g. `A`), but I would prefer not to.

---

A general note: Yes this smells like a design flaw, but I'm making the concious decision to have a very small part of integration code that is slightly hacked, so that all other (larger!) parts can be beautifully independent and well-designed.

Comment: Is the given code fixed as source code, or as its compiled representation? In the former case, you can still do quite a lot of tricks with macros.

Comment: Do you only want `E::foo`? Do you want to leave `E::bar` alone?

Comment: @Marlon: Actually I would like to touch nothing from `E`. As I insinuated: the only changes to the header where `E` is defined I could live with is sneaking a parent class in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers apply - admittedly both treads the borders of your question:

#### 1. Template it

```
template <typename T>
class E {
  void foo() {
    /* ... */
    S s;
    T* t = new T(s);
    /* ... */
    delete t;
    /* ... */
  }
};
```

Now, technically, this did *not* alter the implementation of E::foo... (if you will, it just defined a more generic one).

#### 2. *Evil* Macros

The really -dumb- method that *will* work even in some of the most adverse of circumstances:

```
#define T A::T   // I didn't **recommend** this; it is just _a way_
```

Comment: In a sense the first approach changes the implementation of `E::foo` in the sense that it makes a template of `E`, forcing me to move the >3000 ELOC long implementation of `E` to the header. And the macro is ... well, it's a nice idea, but I cannot say I'm really happy about resorting to preprocessor voodoo (btw. that's not technically part of the C++03 language, but that's nit-picking).

Comment: @bitmask: how is the preprocessor not part of the C++03 standard? I'm just coming up with two sly methods that 'sort of' fit within the description. I could of course say: "You can't" and "You have a design flaw". I thought that would have been unhelpful :)

Comment: Well, if you are really strict, it is not part of the C++ *language*, in the sense that the compiler (I'm excluding the **pre**-processing phase from the compilation phase) doesn't understand a bit of it. But it was just a side-note, never mind.

Comment: @bitmask: let me be really strict and point out that you didn't say "C++03 _language_" in the OP :)

Comment: Okay, you win :)  Nevertheless, you said it yourself: in this case it's kinda *evil* to do this, but it seems like my best shot so far (the template variant is not an option).